# How to properly combine Firestore search with infinite scroll?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

After watching and reading a number of tutorials, I have a solution that allows me to have a list of products on a page and limits the number displayed, increasing as the user scrolls, to prevent exessive reads. This works as expected.

I have since attempted to expand the functionality of this page to allow a user to search through the products using 'array-contains', with each product having an array of keywords that is used as the 'search term'. Again, this feature works... but only when not combined with the ininfite scroll.

My issue is I am struggling to find the correct way to combine the functionality of search and infinite scroll.

My current thought process is that the 'startAfter' part of my query isn't working correctly, however, I'm not 100% certain. It seems that the Observable I use to display the products on my webpage fails to reset when a search query is made.

TypeScript:

```
export class ProductFeedComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(CdkVirtualScrollViewport,  {static: false})
  viewport: CdkVirtualScrollViewport;

  //detects the end of the product list
  theEnd = false;

  offset = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  infinite: Observable<any[]>;
  searchText = '';

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe([Breakpoints.Handset])
  .pipe(
    map(result => result.matches),
    shareReplay()
  );

  constructor(private seo: SeoService, private db: AngularFirestore, private notepad: NotepadsComponent, public dialog: MatDialog, private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    this.searchProducts();
  }

  regularDistribution = 100 / 4 + '%';
  searchQuery: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.seo.generateTags({
      title: 'Product Feed',
      description: 'A catalogue filled with products.'
    });
  }

  openDialog(productName: string){
    this.dialog.open(AddToPadComponent,{
      data: {productData: productName}
    });
  }

  nextBatch(e, offset){
    //checks whether this is the end of the list
    if (this.theEnd)
    {
      return;
    }

    const end = this.viewport.getRenderedRange().end;
    const total = this.viewport.getDataLength();

    console.log(this.viewport.getDataLength());

    if (end === total)
    {
      this.offset.next(offset);
    }
  }

  searchProducts(){
    const batchMap = this.offset.pipe(
      throttleTime(500), mergeMap(n => this.getBatch(n)), scan((acc, batch) => {
        return {...acc, ...batch};
      }, {})
    );

    this.infinite = batchMap.pipe(map(v => Object.values(v)));
  }

  trackByIndex(i){
    return i;
  }

  getBatch(lastSeen: string){
    console.log('firing search...')
    console.log(lastSeen)
    const search = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("productSearch")).value;
    console.log(search);
        return this.db.collection('products', ref => ref.where('keywords', 'array-contains', search).orderBy('productName').startAfter(lastSeen).limit(batchSize))
        .snapshotChanges().pipe(tap(arr => (arr.length ? null : (this.theEnd = true))),map(arr => {
          return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
            const id = cur.payload.doc.id;
            console.log(id);
            const data = cur.payload.doc.data();
            console.log(data);
            return {...acc, [id]: {id, data}};
          }, {});
        })
      );
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input (keyup)="searchProducts()" id="productSearch" placeholder="search products...">

<ng-container *ngIf="infinite | async as products">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="100" (scrolledIndexChange)="nextBatch($event, (products[products.length - 1].data.productName))">
        <div class="product-row" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column wrap" fxFlexFill fxLayoutAlign="center center">  
            <div fxFlex.gt-xs="50%" fxFlex.gt-md="30%" *cdkVirtualFor="let p of products; let i = index; trackByIndex">
                    <mat-card class="product-tile">
                        <img class="product-thumbnail" src= "{{ p.data.thumbnail }}" [routerLink]="p.id">
                        <div class="product-brand">
                            {{ p.id }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="product-details">
                            <span id="product-name">{{ p.data.productName }}</span> <span id="product-price">{{ p.data.price }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-to-pad-button">
                            <button (click)="openDialog(p.id)" mat-raised-button color="accent">Add to Pad</button>
                            <a href="{{ p.data.link }}" class="mat-raised-button color=accent">Click Me</a>
                        </div>
                    </mat-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ng-container>
```

I'm convinced I'm missing something obvious. I know that the function is being correctly as a user searches, however, I'm getting the error "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent]", so something is going wrong with my query, which does not happen when nothing is being searched (e.g. when the page is initially loading).

Working example: https://www.padder.co.uk/catalogue

the two products have searchable values of 'blue' for one and 'purple' for the other. In the same 'keywords' array, which is used to retrieve products, there is a '' value, which should allow all products to show when there is no value entered in the search box, however this does not work as expected.

Comment: can you add a example / code to stack-blitz ?

Comment: @LogicBlower - sorry for the delay. I've now added a link to where you can see the code live

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

As per site link you shared these are my observations: 
You have fired search event on keyUp as you search the terms that doesn't give back any result so below line is error

```
        const data = cur.payload.doc.data();
```

**above line gives you error data of undefined.**  As if i search xyz and no result is there then you get data of undefined error as it does not exists, but if you search for blue you will not get this error as you have result for that , (when response for blue query is returned).

You have to check  where the following object has a data property or not.

what you can do is

```
      const id = cur.payload.doc.id;

      console.log(id);

      let data = ''; // what ever value you need , or a empty object 
     // check for id as, if you have result then id value will be there and then use data 
    if(id){ 
             data = cur.payload.doc.data();
         }

-----
 // or 
if(cur.payload.doc && cur.payload.doc.data){
data = cur.payload.doc.data();
}
```

so you will not get error **cannot read property 'data' of undefined**

Also i will recommend you to add/improve a bit functionality,

1) For Search - use Debounce Time , unique value ,  start search after 2 charter typed for performance side. As right now as you hit a key it fill n/w panel with requests.

2) In template -- `{{ p?.data?.productName }}` -- use this as optional parameter to avoid error in case you are not sure property is there or not

Comment: thank you for your suggestions - I'll give these a go and see how I get on!

Comment: Something I'm not clear on is that although both products have "" (e.g. an empty value) in the keywords array, which the query looks at for which products to return, neither are returned when the search box is empty. Any idea why this behaviour happens?

Comment: ref => ref.where('keywords', 'array-contains', search) -- you have added a where condition that's why it return result according to that , you can add a logic or make a  if else like if search text is empty  call query without where condition and in else call with where as it working right now